# webpack is not defined - gulp - but IS defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, referenceerror, gulp-webpack

I'm using Gulp and webpack, I imported both `webpack` and `webpack-stream` in my gulpfile.js but for some reason the console says `webpack is not defined`

my gulp import are  correct :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
```

My task which should compile

```
gulp.task('webpack', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.srcClient)
        .pipe(webpackStream(require('./webpack.config.js'), webpack))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.buildJs));
```

My webpack config if needed

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client.js',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build/assets/js',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

The error from the output :

```
Starting 'webpack'...
[16:29:38] 'webpack' errored after 2.24 ms
[16:29:38] ReferenceError: webpack is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/k3nzie/projects/jsGame/webpack.config.js:25:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/k3nzie/projects/jsGame/gulpfile.js:28:29)
    at module.exports (/home/k3nzie/projects/jsGame/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
```

Any suggestions? I'm gettin insane lately with webpack...

Comment: You just need to add `var webpack = require('webpack');` to the top of `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack is not defined in it config file.

In top of webpack.config.js, implement :

```
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
```

And in plugins line on webpack.config.js :

```
plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    })
]
```

Comment: I think this solved it, cause it's now thowing an error for module not found (my class that I import, I'm gonna mark this correct anyway, it seems another problem (which is weird cause the dir is correct in my import but it doesn't find it)

Comment: How class ? Uglify plugin ? If yes, make sur you have run in cmd : npm install -D uglify-webpack-plugin

Comment: Actually the problem itself is solved, for other reasons, although I noticed I didn't have uglify-webpack-plugin in my dependencies, so I ran `npm install -D uglify-webpack-plugin` but it says `Not Found: uglify-webpack-plugin@latest`  **edit :** my bad, it actually was `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` not `uglify-webpack-plugin`

Comment: My bad sorry ^^

Answer (score 0):

How did you install webpack? Make sure you have run "npm install webpack", or "npm install webpack -g" (for global system installation)